# Is there a way to use UIView / CALayer in OpenGL or Apple's GLKit without rendering to UIImage/CGImageRef?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, calayer, glkit

I know how to render a UIView/CALayer to a CGContextRef and a UIImage/CGImageRef.. That is old news.

**But** is there a way to omit the rendering to Image/CGContextRef and use the UIView/CALayer directly in OpenGL or GLKit, so that if updates happens in the view it will be reflected in OpenGL/GLKit?

Just like Apple creates that page curl effect the view which is being curled has updates (at least in the "Maps" application - try scrolling some distance and see the tiles being loaded).

Any ideas? I want freedom!!!!

What I in the end want is a way to create different effects in OpenGL / GLKit with a realtime updated UIView with least possible CPU overhead.